# Activate auto-filter for columns D-J based on active checkbox in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have seven form control checkboxes in an excel sheet titled: chkMonday, chkTuesday, chkWednesday, chkThursday, chkFriday, chkSaturday, chkSunday.

In the same sheet there are seven columns, D-J, that represent item quantities for each day of the week.

I have auto-filters created for these columns like the example below:

```
Sub SundayAutofilter()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1000").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("1", _
    "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "M", "T", "W", "F", "S"), 
Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

I am looking for a way to have one macro that uses the checkbox that is selected to choose the correct column to auto-filter.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to check multiple checkboxes? eg. both chkMonday and chkTuesday are checked.

Comment: Ideally I would like for checking one checkbox to automatically uncheck all others to prevent this from throwing an error.  One day should be processed at a time in this workflow.

Comment: I just found you updated OP when I was coding. My answer are for the original question which asked for the dynamic Criteria list.

Comment: @taller The ChkEvent() still works with the array you included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `Caller` to get checkbox control's name
- Update the criteria array before apply autofilter
- All other checkboxes are unchecked when users check a checkbox
- ***Note:*** All checkboxes should be assigned the macro (right-click on checkbox > <kbd>Assign Macro</kbd>) named `ChkEvent()`.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Caller property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133085)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChkEvent()
    Dim aChkBox, aCrit, vVal As Long
    Dim sChkName As String, i As Long, iCol As Long
    Const COL_MONDAY As Long = 4
    aChkBox = Array("chkMonday", "chkTuesday", _
        "chkWednesday", "chkThursday", "chkFriday", "chkSaturday", "chkSunday")
    aCrit = Array("1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", _
        "12", "13", "14", "15", "")
    ' Get the chk name
    On Error Resume Next
        sChkName = Application.Caller
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Len(sChkName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ' Geth the chk location
    For i = 0 To UBound(aChkBox)
        If aChkBox(i) = sChkName Then
            iCol = i + COL_MONDAY
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If iCol = 0 Then Exit Sub
    With ActiveSheet
        ' Get the chk status
        vVal = .CheckBoxes(sChkName).Value
        ' Uncheck all chk
        .CheckBoxes(aChkBox).Value = -4146
        ' Remove filters
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        If vVal = 1 Then ' chk is checked
            .CheckBoxes(sChkName).Value = 1
            ' Update criteria array
            aCrit(UBound(aCrit)) = .Cells(2, iCol)
            .Range("A1:O1000").AutoFilter Field:=iCol, _
                Criteria1:=aCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This works.  I didn't realize at first I had to assign the macro to each checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

### Single Code for Multiple Checkboxes (`Application.Caller`)

```vb
Sub DailyFilter()
    
    Const TABLE_RANGE As String = "A1:O1000"
    Const FIRST_FILTER_COLUMN As Long = 4
    Dim CheckBoxNames() As Variant:
    CheckBoxNames = Array("chkMonday", "chkTuesday", _
        "chkWednesday", "chkThursday", "chkFriday", "chkSaturday", "chkSunday")
    Dim Criteria() As Variant:
    Criteria = Array("1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", _
        "12", "13", "14", "15", "S")
 
    Dim CheckBoxName As String
    On Error Resume Next
        CheckBoxName = Application.Caller
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Len(CheckBoxName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim FilterColumn As Variant:
    FilterColumn = Application.Match(CheckBoxName, CheckBoxNames, 0)
    If IsError(FilterColumn) Then Exit Sub
    
    FilterColumn = FilterColumn + FIRST_FILTER_COLUMN - 1
    
    With ActiveSheet
        If .CheckBoxes(CheckBoxName).Value = 1 Then ' on
            .CheckBoxes(CheckBoxNames).Value = -4146 ' off
            .CheckBoxes(CheckBoxName).Value = 1 ' on
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Range(TABLE_RANGE).AutoFilter Field:=FilterColumn, _
                Criteria1:=Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Else ' off
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
            .CheckBoxes(CheckBoxNames).Value = -4146 ' off
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't wanting to work for my sheet.

Comment: Feel free to download [a copy of my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hZ_AS_z4giq8c3Icw1DJR9264lZtCOEY/view?usp=sharing) from my Google Drive.